# finding coordinate of UIWindow?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am adding subview to master view. But I want to draw that subview based on UIWindow Middle coordinate, not based on superview(masterview)? Is it possible in iPhone SDK?

Comment: have you thought about storing the UIWindow coordinates? Or is it going to be Dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

A view's `frame.origin` is always relative to its superview's bounds and insets. You just need to do the proper conversion. What you probably need is something like:

```
myView.frame = [myWindow convertRect:myView.frame fromView:[myView superview]];
```

I'm not positive that this is exactly what you need, but there are several `convertRect:…` methods on `UIView`. Study their docs and you should know the right thing for your use case. For more help, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382316/how-does-cgrectconvertrectcgrectrect-toviewuiview-view-work).

Note that this only works after all the views are added as subviews in a consistent structure. It won't work before they are assembled.